# OpenSSL random - using ENGINE API to set random, what is the right way to do it?

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

In OpenSSL, using an engine taking use of hardware, I'm trying to make sure the RAND_bytes will use the engine and hardware. I came across two functions:

```
ENGINE_set_default_RAND(ENGINE*)
RAND_set_rand_engine(ENGINE*)
```

Seemingly - they do the same. Why are there two of them? Which one is the right way to go?

I've further tested if *set* functions work by disconnecting the hardware and performing init, then RAND_bytes. Using the first function only (ENGINE_set_default_RAND) everything suceeded - obviously the software implementation was used (why?). When changed to the second it failed on the *set* RAND_set_rand_engine function call (which is great).

Comment: I think the first resets the random engine to default and the second sets a new random engine. cf: http://docs.webingenia.com/openssl/doxygen/tb__rand_8c.html#aff986867c525f7f1011a291968099320 and http://docs.webingenia.com/openssl/doxygen/include_2openssl_2rand_8h.html#a6a4f2c2cf723ef63522d4b33c79d5f0f

Comment: midor, thank you for the docs! But shouldn't the end result be the same, as the ENGINE_set_default accepts an Engine to be made default?

Comment: I am sorry, I have done some stuff with this in the past, but I don't remember well enough anymore to give a precise answer. I'll try to explain, since no one else seems to care. I remember the ENGINE being a newer API, deprecating parts of RAND, but I don't know about this specific function. It must be newer since it knows about ENGINE. The manpages for both engine and rand seem to support my recollections. I think the engine-manpage is quite useful: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/engine.html# It also links rand's manpage so I won't add a link. I would say ENGINE_x is the way to go now.

Comment: midor, thank you, from my tests RAND_set_rand_engine is the only one to work, but I'm afraid this can be this particular ENGINE specific. If you like, please answer the question with the comment's content so I can accept it (it answers the question).

Comment: To be honest I think I did not really answer the question, so I think it is not in the interest of people who will read this in the future if I batch some links together. It would probably better, if you explained how you resolved this issue for yourself and posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/engine.html#Application_requirements *ENGINE_set_default_(ENGINE*)* is the way to go, e.g.:

```
ENGINE_set_default_RAND(myPtrEngine);
```

which worked, effectively causing the engine implementation to be used. I've tested it by modifying the custom engine code, injecting it with some simple *printfs(...)* to indicate the flow (had some problems with debugging).

The other call:

```
RAND_set_rand_engine(myPtrEngine);
```

resulted in essentially the same (I do not know the internal differences).

The problem that caused me to ask, was the possibility of a fallback-to-software mechanism. With the hardware disconnected and the engine using it set, the random functions seemingly worked. I therefore did not know whether the *ENGINE_set_default_RAND* worked. After examining the engine's code, however, it turned out it itself had a fallback mechanism. That's why it *always* worked.